# EWS :- Unable to load resources for resource file "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Strings"

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, exchangewebservices

I am developing a window 8 metro app where i have to use the ExchaneWebServices to create tasks and display all tasks back into my app. I used the following code.

```
service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(userEmail, userPassword); 
service.AutodiscoverUrl(userEmail, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

I am getting error on auto discover. I used that same code with console application and it works fine. Is there some problem with exchange service and metro app?

Comment: I don't have specific expertise here, but [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/61a93c9e-ad74-472b-9c39-072d2d855e7b) seems relevant